# How do i get the minutes part when i subtract two time values

Tags: c#, datetime

I want minutes part when i subtract two time values.
I am subtracting current time with 11:30 PM and the result i need in minutes.

I am trying the following code in c#.

```
TimeSpan eTs = new TimeSpan(23, 30, 00);
int min = System.DateTime.Now.Minute - eTs.Minutes;
```

but its giving wrong values.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by >the result i need in minutes< - can you please give a input/output pair as an example

Comment: If you say _gives wrong values_ in your question, you should tell _that_ wrong values and what do you except as a _right_ values also.

Answer (score 3):

It gives wrong value because you are substracting ints. It could even give negative numbers. You should substract the TimeSpan from the DateTime, which gives you another DateTime and use it's Minute property.

```
var eTs = new TimeSpan(23, 30, 00);
var min = (System.DateTime.Now - eTs).Minute;
```

**EDIT**

> I am subtracting current time with 11:30 PM and the result i need in
>   minutes.

No, you are substracting 23 hours and 30 minutes from the current date time.
If you want to know how much minutes have passed since 11:30 PM (what day/month/year), you should:

```
var min = (System.DateTime.Now - somePastDate).TotalMinutes; //somePastDate must be a DateTime
```

Comment: This just gives the minute component.  If the timespan in minutes is needed then a conversion from Hours:Minutes:seconds to minutes is required.

Comment: I too think that this might or might not be the answer - the question is just not clear

Comment: He already has the timespan! He creates it. If he needs the total minutes he could just use eTs.TotalMinutes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna subtract 2 dateTime and Get the total in minutes try this:

```
    DateTime data = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime data2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
    TimeSpan sub = data - data2;
    Console.WriteLine(sub.TotalMinutes);
```

Or If you wanna subtract minutes from a datetime try this

```
    TimeSpan eTs = new TimeSpan(23, 30, 00);    
    DateTime data2 = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-eTs.TotalMinutes);
    Console.WriteLine(data2);
```